# How to access a variable from one form script into another one form script in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, variables, inheritance, label

I'm trying to make an turn-based RPG Game on Visual Studio using Windows Forms and the C# language, as an alternative for studying.
But no matter how much I search (I think I searched almost the entire internet), it seems like no one in this planet has asked this question just once before...
The question is:
I have two forms, the c# script on the first one is the place where I stored every single basic information about the Player (Health, Strength, Etc.), and then I have the second form, that is a form where I put on the screen, labels containing the player informations that I stored in the first form script.
But seems like I just cannot do this, because there's no information about showing on another form any public static int or string variables declared on a first form.

I need to use some type of reference? Or should I create a "master script file" to store these values?

If anyone can please explain me how do I take the information on that variables that until now I haven't used, and place it on labels installed in another form, I would be eternally grateful.
Thank you for reading so much text and I hope my english is not so bad (Isn't my native language).

Comment: There is so much to explain to cover that that it is beyond the SO remit. However, there are many tutorials out there.  Grab yourself a teach yourself c# book and it will cover it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
This is my first post here on Stack Overflow, I will try my best to be more objective next time!

Answer (score 0):

You should really run through a basic tutorial or read a book before you come to Stack Overflow to ask..

Generally you'd create a [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes) that stores the player's information.

```
internal class PlayerInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Health { get; set; }
}
```

Your forms then hold a private variable of type `PlayerInfo` like so:

```
private PlayerInfo playerInfo;
```

And create a instance of it for your whole program

```
this.playerInfo = new PlayerInfo
{
    Name = "Player1",
    Health = 100
}
```

I assume you'd want to create that instance in your first form and pass it to the second form. When creating your second form you need to have a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) that accepts the `PlayerInfo` as a parameter.

```
public Form2(PlayerInfo playerInfo)
{
    this.playerInfo = playerInfo;
    ...
}
```

In both forms you can then access the player's information by using `this.playerInfo.Health` or `this.playerInfo.Name` etc.

Comment: Hi biesi, thank you for your answer, I believe that the internet is a place to answer simple doubts, while books and academic texts stand for true specialization.
The good news is that other people with the same doubts, now with your answer, can have their doubts answered too when searching for it on Google as I did.
---
But speaking of doubts, when you say "create a instance of it for your whole program", you mean that I need to include this code on every "form.cs" I have created?
I tried to do this, but it's doesn't seem to recognize my previous created class. I am missing something?

Comment: As I already said, you should really grab a book (or watch a video tutorial, there are plenty on YouTube) about object oriented programming or C#. They will explain what instances, objects, classes etc. are way better than I can do. To make it short: You only have to ceate the instance once using the `new` keyword. After it's been created, you can pass that instance around using a variable and parameters, as I've shown you.

Comment: I'll try,
Thank you for your support!